# Problema com registro duplicado mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho um script que recebe solicitações do mercado livre quando há alguma atualização em um pedido.

Quando um pedido é feito, o mercado livre envia de 5 a 10 solicitações para esse script praticamente ao mesmo tempo (nao me pergunte porque ele manda tantas solicitações ao mesmo tempo, pois todas sao iguais), e eu insiro no meu banco apenas uma delas.

O problema esta basicamente nas linhas abaixo, que verificam se já foi inserido o pedido na tabela do banco. ($obj_sql é um simples manipulador do mysql, e acho que o problema nao esta nele.)

```
$jatemped = $obj_sql->Get("select count(ped_id) from pedidos where mel_order='$id_order'");
if ($jatemped===0) {
   $obj_sql->Query("insert into pedidos (mel_order) values ('".$id_order."')");
}
```

o campo mel_order não é unico, pois pode conter registros na tabela pedidos com esse campo em branco.

O problema é que algumas vezes, o insert é duplicado por uma segunda requisição do script, com o mesmo $id_order no campo mel_order.

Será que há algum tipo de cache entre o insert e o select da proxima execução do script que ele nao consegue ver o insert que acabou de ser feito?

Como posso resolver isso?

Comment: como é essas solicitações do mercado livre? consegue postar?

Comment: O que pode ajudar você é utilizar transações, que estão disponíveis no MySQL para a Engine InnoDB. Com uma transação é possível trancar a tabela ou linhas enquanto está ocorrendo operações de escrita no banco de dados. Documentação: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-transaction-model.html

Comment: Provavelmente é um Race Condition, as duas requisições chegaram no mesmo ponto ao mesmo tempo, assim para ambas o `$jatemped` é `0`, isso é algo previsível e um tanto lógico uma vez que não há nada que bloqueie. O ideal é que você utilize o UNIQUE, o resto é gambiarra. Uma das outras gambiarras é utilizar `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` dentro de uma `TRANSCATION` ou executar um `INSERT SELECT ... WHERE NOT EXISTS ....` também dentro da transação.

Comment: Tente alterando `count(ped_id)` para somente `ped_id` e na comparação IF, altere para `if (mysql_fetch_array($jatemped) === false) {`. Acho desnecessário contar o número de registros com `count()`, uma vez que vc só quer saber se o registro existe ou não com o `$id_order`. Acho bem melhor obter um booleano (talvez mais rápido até).

Comment: @DiegoLela as solicitações são post com um json no corpo. acho que esse nao é o problema, pois eu consigo identificar certinho o conteudo.. a questão é que as chamadas são ao mesmo tempo, e primeiro select com o count nao consegue identificar que uma outra transação quase que ao mesmo tempo ja inseriu.

Comment: @DavidSamm vou fazer essa alteração para ver se ajuda tambem

Comment: @Inkeliz é possivel ter um campo com chave unica apenas quando o campo nao é null ou em branco? pois esse campo existe varios registros com o valor em branco para o campo mel_order.

Comment: @RodrigoVicentin, sim. Por padrão inclusive, "For all engines, a UNIQUE index permits multiple NULL values for columns that can contain NULL.", [veja a documentação](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html). Desde que seja realmente NULL (e tabela permita NULL)  poderá ter múltiplos NULL, mesmo em UNIQUE.